# Run bash script from curl failed while from file succeeded

Tags: bash

I have a script `install.sh` essentially looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -f "/usr/bin/jq" ]]; then
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq
fi

echo $(date) >> install.log
```

If I put it on a server, and run it like this:

```
curl -s0 https://myserver.com/install.sh | bash
```

after the crazy `apt-get` output, it won't run the last `echo` line, instead it prints the line `echo $(date) >> test.log` as output. While if I save the `install.sh` on the disk, and run `./install.sh`, it runs as expected. the echo line is executed and the `install.log` is appended.

To further reproduce this issue, I run it locally like this:

```
cat install.sh | bash
```

it also has the same problem.

I run `apt-get remove jq` manually before each test. If `jq` is installed, then both work as expected. So why it's different to run it from the download vs. run it from local file?

I recorded a short video to demonstrate this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYvGXI7AibA

Comment: So the question is: "what is the difference between `bash foo` and `bash <foo`". (It is not really curl related.)

Comment: Right, thanks. What is the difference to the code after `apt-get` is run between `bash foo` and `bash <foo`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your described behavior. If you replace the apt-get line with a simple echo, does it still show that behavior? Try to run with `bash -x`.

Comment: I can't reproduce either, but I am using http, not https.

Comment: @michas sorry I was buy just now. I will try it at a later time. @Archemar, can you reproduce it using `cat install.sh | bash`?

Comment: @michas simple echo does not cause this problem. `bash -x` with `apt-get` still cause the same problem. Interesting two people said they cannot reproduce the problem. I will record a video and show you later.

Comment: `bash -x` does not **solve** the problem. But it should **show** you the problem. What is the difference in the output of `bash -x foo` and `bash -x <foo`?

Comment: @michas I recorded a short video to reproduce this problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYvGXI7AibA

Comment: presumably you are doing this because you want to install `jq` on multiple hosts, perhaps on a cluster.  If so, look into installing `pdsh` (available packaged for debian etc), so you can then run commands like `pdsh -g all apt-get -y install jq`.   or `pdcp -g all myscript.sh /tmp ; pdsh -g all bash /tmp/myscript.sh`.   See https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html

Comment: @cas, no, that's not the point of this question. I'm writing a script that installs another script that depends on `jq`. So I need to make sure `jq` is installed when the install script is run successfully.

Comment: Then why go out of your way to make the process so complicated?  why fetch it with curl and pipe it into bash when you can just run the script?  the only time i've seen people do things like that is when they're writing a `for h in $hosts ; do ... ; done` wrapper around ssh, and `pdsh` is a much better tool for that job.  if it doesn't need to be complicated, then keep it simple.

Comment: or are you writing this to go with some install instructions on your website?  if so, please don't do that.  there's already way too many people telling ignorant users to do that - and they really don't need to be taught that fetching random scripts from random web sites and running them without examination as root is an acceptable thing to do,  Give them the instructions, tell them what to do.  If you want to give them a script to automate the process, tell them to download it as a separate step and EXAMINE IT (and perhaps modify it to suit their system) before running it,

Comment: @cas that's exactly the case. Sounds silly and rude, but it just does the work. I will ask user to provide a key as parameter and it will read more parameters from my website as JSON. that's how I customize the behavior of the script to suit their systems.

Comment: You are doing your users no favours at all by teaching them that security is irrelevant, or by treating them as idiots who can't follow simple instructions.  Have some respect for your users, and assume they're at least moderately intelligent and capable.  At the very least, warn them that by running your script without examining it, they are giving YOU complete root access to their system.

Comment: When we talk about security, we define a security boundary. Anything inside the boundary is considered trusted, anything outside is considered dangerous. So to justify something is secure or not, it depends on where you draw the security boundary line. For example, when I install a package from apt-get, I would not look at their source code at all, unless it doesn't work as expected, even if they warn me to check that, since I consider that to be in my security boundary. Back to my script, I just provide certain level of convenience. They still can download and check that if they like.

Comment: You might know that you are trustworthy but  nobody else knows you from a bar of soap.  By telling your users to run your script as root, you're telling them "trust me. give me unrestricted root access to your system".  official debian repos are curated, and monitored and with a bug tracking system.  your web site with your script is just a random web site, one amongst billions.  If you seriously think what you are telling your users to do is in any way acceptable practice then you are simply not qualified to talk about security.  you have decided that minor convenience is far more important.

Comment: @cas aha! I got your ideas. It's about root access. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: No, actually, it's about training users to do things they shouldn't do, things that they should have more sense than to do.  You're encouraging them to indulge in dangerous behaviour and teaching them that it's perfectly normal and OK to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `bash` does not care whether it is reading its commands from a file (as in `bash foo`) or from STDIN (as in `bash <foo`). However now you start a command (`apt-get`) which itself wants to ask the user and uses, yes, STDIN to do so.

Therefore weird things happen: bash reads commands from STDIN and executes them one by one. Now one of the command reads from STDIN and, well, reads the next line of the file. Afterwards bash reads the next line from STDIN and therefore skips the one command already read by the other command.

This small script will demonstrate what is going on:

```
echo "hello"
read -p "how do you do? "
echo "I understand"
echo "you are '$REPLY'."
echo "bye"
```

Save it in a file and first run it as `bash -x foo` and afterwards as `bash -x <foo`.

The same thing will happen in you example.

One solution would be to use process substitution:

```
bash -x <(cat foo)
```

or in your case simply:

```
bash <(curl -s0 https://myserver.com/install.sh)
```

---

Some remarks:

Whenever some shell script does weird things, use `bash -x` to see what is going on.

Writing `cat foo| ...` is known as [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat). Just use redirection instead.

Comment: Why does `apt-get install -y ...` still read from _stdin_?

Comment: Interesting. `apt-get install -y ...` does NOT flush _stdin_. At least in my test example. Consider `apt-get -y purge fonts-georgewilliams; apt-get ( echo 1; echo 2; echo 3 ) | ( apt-get -y install fonts-georgewilliams; read x; echo "x=$x" )` the output is `1`.

Comment: Thanks @michas, it works. But I still don't understand why it's like this. Is `apt-get` doing any nasty thing?

Comment: Well kind not really nasty things. It just reads from STDIN, which is usually fine and the normal way to get input from the user. But if you tell Bash to to read its commands from STDIN, too, then both read from the same source, which, well, leads to "unexpected" results. (The only strange thing is, why `apt-get` reads from STDIN at all, because it needs to ask no question.) But generally it is just fine for a command to read from STDIN and exactly this is the reason, why process substitution exists and should be used in that case.